# Dictionary for MS Works 9.0 word processor

Tags: boot, dictionary, microsoft-works

64-bit Vista

I never use Works, but I used to keep the word processor's dictionary open. Now I want to do so again, but can't fine the dictionary's filename so I can put it in my Startup folder.

So, what is the dictionary's filename?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The filename is WksDict.exe .